# React: Sticky header flickers in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sticky, onscroll

I'm using the following code in React to set a sticky header.  I've included `top` and `setTop` to demonstrate what's causing the problem.  I'm not including the CSS for the header because the value of `top` reveals that the issue is not with the CSS (I can update the question if necessary).

```
const BodyHeader = props => {
    const [top,setTop] = useState(0);
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const handleScroll = () => {
        if (!ref.current) return;
        setTop(ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().top);
        const classList = ref.current.classList;
        if (ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().top < 1) {
            if (!classList.contains("sticky-header")) {
                classList.add("sticky-header");
            }
        } else {
            classList.remove("sticky-header");
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', () => handleScroll);
        };
    }, []);

    return <div id="body-header" ref={ref}>
        <div id="header-inner">
            <div style={{color: "red"}}>{top}</div>*/}
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

What I'm seeing in iOS Safari is that the value of `top` jumps all over the place.  I originally had `ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 0`, however, after adding the `div` with `top`, I saw that the value was jumping to small fractional values when scrolling.  Changing this to `< 1` removes most of the issue, however, if I quickly scroll and release my thumb and just let it free scroll without my thumb touching, it will start to flicker again.

It's especially bad when I scroll back to the top of the page.  It's like Safari is calculating where the div will be after scrolling has stopped (rather than where it currently is).  This issue is not occurring in Chrome or Safari on macOS.

I am also using this CSS on the body:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Is there something that needs to change in the JS or additional CSS that affects scrolling?  I'm changing more than just the position of the header, so I need to add the class rather than just using `position: sticky`.

I've seen a number of similar questions about flashing headers, but I haven't seen where this specific issue has been addressed.

Comment: Could you put your code into a snippet so we can try it [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty simple solution.  I just had to add a wrapper div that would serve as the reference rather than the div that I wanted to make sticky:

```
return <div className="body-header-wrapper" ref={ref}>
    <div id="body-header">
        <div id="header-inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`body-header-wrapper` is the new div and `ref={ref}` has been moved there.  The idea is that, even though its child div, `body-header`, is still unbstable in terms of its absolute position from the top due to the sticky positioning (I double checked by displaying the value of `top` as I did previously), `body-header-wrapper` is not being repositioned and therefore the flickering is no longer happening.